# Issue with the Tic-Tac-Toe game (I suspect the cause is in the cheack_win function)

Tags: python, tic-tac-toe

I have an issue with my Tic-Tac-Toe game. I suspect the error is in the `cheack_win` function.

If someone could explain to me what I could do to **prevent the console from returning the error**, I would appreciate it.

```
import numpy
import numpy as np

def print_board(board):
    for i in board:
        print(" ")
        for x in i:
            print(x, end=" | ")

def player_X(x):
    if x == "A1":
        board[1][1] = "X"
        print_board(board)
    if x == "A2":
        board[1][2] = "X"
        print_board(board)
    if x == "A3":
        board[1][3] = "X"
        print_board(board)
    if x == "B1":
        board[2][1] = "X"
        print_board(board)
    if x == "B2":
        board[2][2] = "X"
        print_board(board)
    if x == "B3":
        board[2][3] = "X"
        print_board(board)
    if x == "C1":
        board[3][1] = "X"
        print_board(board)
    if x == "C2":
        board[3][2] = "X"
        print_board(board)
    if x == "C3":
        board[3][3] = "X"
        print_board(board)
    return board

def player_Y(y):
    if y == "A1":
        board[1][1] = "O"
        print_board(board)
    if y == "A2":
        board[1][2] = "O"
        print_board(board)
    if y == "A3":
        board[1][3] = "O"
        print_board(board)
    if y == "B1":
        board[2][1] = "O"
        print_board(board)
    if y == "B2":
        board[2][2] = "O"
        print_board(board)
    if y == "B3":
        board[2][3] = "O"
        print_board(board)
    if y == "C1":
        board[3][1] = "O"
        print_board(board)
    if y == "C2":
        board[3][2] = "O"
        print_board(board)
    if y == "C3":
        board[3][3] = "O"
        print_board(board)
    return board

def get_uniq_values(row_set):
    result = row_set - {"A", "B", "C"}
    return result

def cheack_win(board):
    prepared_set = get_uniq_values(set(board))

    for row in prepared_set:

        if len(prepared_set(row)) == 1:
            print("Wygrywający to:", set(row))

        elif len(prepared_set(row)) == 1:
            board_transposed = np.transpose(prepared_set)
            print("Wygrywający to: ", set(row))

    for x in board:
        if (board[1][1] == board[2][2] == board[3][3]) or (board[1][3] == board[2][2] == board[3][1]):
            print("Wygranym jest: ", x)

print("Tic-Tac-Toe game")
print("-------------------------------------------------------")

board = [
    [" ", 1, 2, 3],
    ["A", ".", ".", "."],
    ["B", ".", ".", "."],
    ["C", ".", ".", "."],
]
print_board(board)

move_counter = 0

while move_counter < 3:
    x = input("\n Player X choose: ")
    player_X(x)

    y = input("\n Player Y choose: ")
    player_Y(y)

    move_counter += 1

cheack_win(board)
```

After code execution:

```
prepared_set = get_uniq_values(set(board))
TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'
```

Comment: The error message tells you *exactly* where the symptom is.

Comment: Are you able to tell me how I can fix it 
I've tried different ways but I feel like my head is stuck?

Comment: What do you think `set(board)` is supposed to accomplish, given that `board` is a list of lists of strings?

Comment: So I understand that I should change the get_uniq_values function so that it subtracts the letters "A", "B", "C" from the list and not from the set?

Comment: You can't make a set from a list of lists.

Comment: When I wrote set(board) I thought board would turn into set and subtract "A", "B", "C" from it

Comment: And now you know it won't.

Comment: well thank you for your help I will try to do it another way